# Key error when joining dfs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with these columns:

```
df1:

Index(['cnpj', '#CNAE', 'Estado', 'Capital_Social', '#CNAEpai', '#CNAEvo',
   '#CNAEbisavo', 'Porte'],
  dtype='object')
```

I have another dataframe with these columns:

```
df2:

Index(['#CNAEpai', 'ROA_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'MgBruta_t12_Peers_CNAEpai',
   'MgEBITDA_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'LiqCorrente_t12_Peers_CNAEpai',
   'Crescimento_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'MgLucro_t12_Peers_CNAEpai',
   'Custo/Receita_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'Passivo/EBITDA_t12_Peers_CNAEpai',
   'ROE_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'RFinanceiro/Receita_t12_Peers_CNAEpai',
   'cnpj_t12_Peers_CNAEpai', 'LiqGeral_t12_Peers_CNAEpai'],
  dtype='object')
```

I'm trying to join them, using this line:

```
df1=df1.join(df2,on=['#CNAEpai'],how='left',rsuffix='_bbb')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
KeyError: '#CNAEpai'
```

Since #CNAEpai is a column in both dfs that shouldn't be happening right?
What's going on?

Comment: do you want `merge` instead of `join`?

Comment: I tried that with merge but for some reason I can't explain it was killing my memory (I have multiple joins in a sequence and at certain point it stopped working)

Comment: well `join` requires index as the merge key for the right frames (`on` only effects the left frame), so it looks like you're trying to use the wrong method if you want  the '#CNAEpai' column to be the merge key for both frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @root indicated, [`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) joins index-on-index or index-on-column, but *not* column-on-column.

To join on column(s), use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='#CNAEpai', how='left', rsuffix='_bbb')
```